# Transformation rules of a linear operator $S\mathbf y = A \mathbf x \implies \mathbf y' = AS \mathbf x'$

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Given are the equations

$$
\mathbf x = S \mathbf x' \tag{8.91} 
$$
$$
\mathbf y = A \mathbf x, \quad \mathbf y' = A'\mathbf x' \tag{8.93} 
$$

It (Riley Hobson Bence, 3rd) then says,

> But using $(8.91)$, we may rewrite the first equation as
> $$
> S\mathbf y' = AS\mathbf x' \implies \mathbf y' = S^{-1} AS \mathbf x'.
> $$

Now, intuitively, I believe that $\mathbf y' = S^{-1} AS \mathbf x'$ holds. Also, I don't dispute the implication above; it just results by multiplying $S^{-1}$ on the left of the left hand side.

But I'm at odds on how the text arrives at $S\mathbf y' = AS\mathbf x'$, that is, without assuming that $\mathbf y' = S^{-1} AS \mathbf x'$ holds. How does this follow from $(8.91)$, like the text says?

In other words, I'm unable to *derive* how we arrive at $S\mathbf y' = AS\mathbf x'$, without assuming $\mathbf y' = S^{-1} AS \mathbf x'$.

I've tried the following:

$$
\mathbf y'= A'\mathbf x' \tag{1}
$$
Multiplying by $S$, we get
$$
S \mathbf y' = SA'\mathbf x'  \tag{2}
$$
$(2)$, is in disagreement with the text $S\mathbf y' = A'S\mathbf x'$

**Edit.** Removed the second part of the question, which included a typo.

Comment: For the last part: you are starting with $y=S^{-1}ASx'$ instead of $y'=S^{-1}ASx'$. This could be the cause for the mistake.

Comment: Don't you think (8.91) is implicitly meant to hold for *all* vectors, so that also $\mathbf{y}=S\mathbf{y}'$?

Comment: @Lukas Yes, indeed. I've removed that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing piece of information, it seems, is that (8.91) is also supposed to tell us something about $\mathbf y$. In particular, we have
$$
\mathbf y = S\mathbf y'.
$$
With that, we have
$$
\mathbf y = A \mathbf x \implies
S\mathbf y' = A (S \mathbf x') \implies
\mathbf y' = S^{-1}AS \mathbf x'.
$$